# NiFi - Stop upon failure

Tags: apache-nifi

I've been trying to google and search stack for the answer but have beeen unable to find.

Using NiFi, is it possible to stop a process upon previous job failure?

We have user data we need to process but the data is sequentially constructed so that if a job fails, we need to stop further jobs from running.

I understand we can create scripts to fail a process upon previous process failure, but what if I need entire group to halt upon failure, is this possible? We don't want each job in queue to follow failure path, we want it to halt until we can look at the data and analyze the failure.

TL;DR - can we STOP a process upon a failure, not just funnel all remaining jobs into the failure flow. We want data in queues to wait until we fix, thus stop process, not just fail again and again.

Thanks for any feedback, cheers!

Edit: typos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can configure backpressure on the queues to stop upstream processes.  If you set the backpressure threshold to 1 on a failure queue, it would effectively stop the processor until you had a chance to address the failure.

[image]

[image]

The screenshot shows failure routing back to the processor, but this is not required.  It is important that the next processor should not remove it from the queue to maintain the backpressure until you take action.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is interesting the only way to do this is via back pressure but if it works, it works. Cheers!

Comment: So I noticed that while this effectively stops the processor, it does not prevent the processor from retrying and failing the same file over and over. While files in the queue going into the processor are not processed, the failed file is reprocessed, failed, repeat over and over.

Is there no other way to STOP a process upon failure?

Comment: You do not have to route the failure queue back to the processor as shown in the screenshot.  You can route it elsewhere so it doesn't retry.  Routing failure to a stopped processor, like LogAttribute, would apply the backpressure without retrying.  But it is important that it not be removed from the failure queue, as that would release the backpressure.

Comment: NiFi's design emphasizes flow of individual files over collective job tracking.  The framework is trying to allow files to succeed or fail individually, and for individual failure to not impede subsequent files.